# Phaser attach signal to game input

Tags: javascript, oop, phaser-framework

I'm trying to understand how phaser works, using phaser classes to create an object without gameObjectFactory. I have the following code:

```
var controler = new Phaser.Input(game);
var printSomthing = new Phaser.Signal();
    printSomthing.add(function(){
            alert("anything")
        });
controler.onDown = printSomthing;
```

But the code is not working, and there are no errors in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cant' replace 'onDown', because it's already a signal.

```
controller.onDown.add(function(){
            alert("anything")
        });
```

And if You're really

> trying to understand how phaser work

... it's best to just check rich base of Phaser examples and a documentation.

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/input

Comment: @skywalker  
take this for en example: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/key  
add in create() function (You can edit code in a livecode box)

    game.input.onDown.add(function(){alert("onDown");});
click and alert will show up